# Call bash command within C file with a variable

Tags: c, linux, bash

I hope my question is clear. I need to read a file in C, store the contents of the file and then use this variable in a bash script.

For example, there is a file called "test.txt" which contains "aaa". Here is the call in C:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

char ch;
FILE *fp;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char contents[9] = "";
    if( fp == NULL ) {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) {
      contents[i]=ch;
      i++;
    }
    contents[9]=0;
    fclose(fp);
    system( "echo 'hi'");
    puts(contents);
}
```

Now I need to use a bash script to read the file name that has the "aaa" in its name.

```
system("cat /home/user/$contents.txt");
```

I have tried finding some other solutions but I have only encountered popen so far that I failed to implement. If I used bash, its a very simple one liner, thus why I am trying to implement it. Are there any other options?

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you thought about using `sprintf` familiy of functions?

Comment: I have tried using popen, but that did not work out so well.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What have you tried? Show us your code? Your C variables are not known in the bash. You need to replace the variable already in the command string you provide to the shell.

Comment: Sprintf could only simplify reading from file for me or am I missing something here?

Comment: You need to create the command line for your bash command. This can be done using `snprintf` or `g_strdup_printf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe you can pass `contents` to bash via environment variable.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access

here's an example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
  char * message = "hello";
  setenv("contents", message, 1);
  system("echo $contents");
}
```

the output of this script is

```
hello
```